# Flutter: D/ConnectivityManager(32004): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10294, CallingPid : 32004

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test, flutter-build

I am new to flutter development. I have been editing a code bought from CodeCanyon. This application gets data from Woocommerce REST API. The application built is not showing any product in the output. Instead I have a huge log that shows the issue but I am unable to solve searching the whole internet.

Following is my Run Log:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G935L in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65194/Vb6YpvVgyPs=/ws
Syncing files to device SM G935L...
D/libGLESv2(32004): STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.haris.com
I/System.out(32004): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(32004): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
E/OneSignal(32004): promptPermission() is not applicable in Android
I/zygote64(32004): find the special shared library, skip check
I/zygote64(32004): find the special shared library, skip check
I/DynamiteModule(32004): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:212910700
I/DynamiteModule(32004): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 212910700
D/DynamitePackage(32004): Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
D/DynamitePackage(32004): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
D/ConnectivityManager(32004): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10294, CallingPid : 32004
I/Ads     (32004): Updating ad debug logging enablement.
W/ConnectionStatusConfig(32004): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.leibniz.events.service.START
E/GmsClient(32004): unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.leibniz.events.service.START on com.google.android.gms
I/zygote64(32004): no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
I/zygote64(32004): Do full code cache collection, code=122KB, data=83KB
I/zygote64(32004): After code cache collection, code=121KB, data=64KB
I/WebViewFactory(32004): Loading com.android.chrome version 94.0.4606.61 (code 460606123)
I/cr_WVCFactoryProvider(32004): Loaded version=94.0.4606.61 minSdkVersion=24 isBundle=true multiprocess=true packageId=2
I/cr_LibraryLoader(32004): Successfully loaded native library
I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder(32004): Flushed 8 samples from 8 histograms.
W/ResourceType(32004): Failure getting entry for 0x7f1307e4 (t=18 e=2020) (error -2147483647)
D/ConnectivityManager(32004): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10294, CallingPid : 32004
W/cr_media(32004): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
W/Ads     (32004): Update ad debug logging enablement as false
W/OkHttpClient(32004): A connection to https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
W/OneSignal(32004): LocationController startGetLocation not possible, no location dependency found
I/FirebaseApp(32004): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app ONESIGNAL_SDK_FCM_APP_NAME
I/zygote64(32004): Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=80KB
I/flutter (32004): bool - IS_NOTIFICATION_ON - true
I/zygote64(32004): After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=81KB
I/zygote64(32004): Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(32004): Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=bdb94a0e-9596-425d-924d-bb2ae8840316, tags={ com.onesignal.OSNotificationRestoreWorkManager$NotificationRestoreWorker } ]
I/System.out(32004): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(32004): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/flutter (32004): int - CARTCOUNT - 0
I/flutter (32004): int - CARTCOUNT - 0
I/flutter (32004): http://everfitstore.com/wc/v3/products/categories?oauth_consumer_key=ck_2345365e7b82b6055bcbd459724e9c37060147a3&oauth_nonce=qmdhcusgxm&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1632908629&oauth_token=&oauth_version=1.0&page=1&parent=0&per_page=50&oauth_signature=RCccBRrgdGxEyBUDv0jc%2Ffc7JXs%3D
D/ConnectivityManager(32004): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10294, CallingPid : 32004
I/flutter (32004): http://everfitstore.com/woobox-api/api/v1/woocommerce/get-dashboard?oauth_consumer_key=ck_2345365e7b82b6055bcbd459724e9c37060147a3&oauth_nonce=miemhbtfox&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1632908629&oauth_token=&oauth_version=1.0&per_page=4&oauth_signature=UZsfy6dmyrSjC4%2FFgdx1n7AtuFs%3D
I/flutter (32004): 404 http://everfitstore.com/woobox-api/api/v1/woocommerce/get-dashboard?oauth_consumer_key=ck_2345365e7b82b6055bcbd459724e9c37060147a3&oauth_nonce=miemhbtfox&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1632908629&oauth_token=&oauth_version=1.0&per_page=4&oauth_signature=UZsfy6dmyrSjC4%2FFgdx1n7AtuFs%3D
I/flutter (32004): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (32004): <!--[if IE 9 ]> <html lang="en-US" class="ie9 loading-site no-js"> <![endif]-->
I/flutter (32004): <!--[if IE 8 ]> <html lang="en-US" class="ie8 loading-site no-js"> <![endif]-->
I/flutter (32004): <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en-US" class="loading-site no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
I/flutter (32004): <head>
I/flutter (32004):  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
I/flutter (32004):  <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
I/flutter (32004):  <link rel="pingback" href="https://everfitstore.com/xmlrpc.php" />
I/flutter (32004): 
I/flutter (32004):                  <script>document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className + ' yes-js js_active js'</script>
I/flutter (32004):              <script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>
I/flutter (32004): <title>Page not found &#8211; Everfit Outfits</title>
I/flutter (32004): <meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large' />
I/flutter (32004): <script>window._wca = window._wca || [];</script>
I/flutter (32004): <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /><link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//stats.wp.com' />
I/flutter (32004): <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com
I/flutter (32004): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (32004): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (32004): ^
I/flutter (32004): testPlease try again later.
I/flutter (32004): 200 http://everfitstore.com/wc/v3/products/categories?oauth_consumer_key=ck_2345365e7b82b6055bcbd459724e9c37060147a3&oauth_nonce=qmdhcusgxm&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1632908629&oauth_token=&oauth_version=1.0&page=1&parent=0&per_page=50&oauth_signature=RCccBRrgdGxEyBUDv0jc%2Ffc7JXs%3D
I/flutter (32004): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (32004): <!--[if IE 9 ]> <html lang="en-US" class="ie9 loading-site no-js"> <![endif]-->
I/flutter (32004): <!--[if IE 8 ]> <html lang="en-US" class="ie8 loading-site no-js"> <![endif]-->
I/flutter (32004): <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en-US" class="loading-site no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
I/flutter (32004): <head>
I/flutter (32004):  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
I/flutter (32004):  <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
I/flutter (32004):  <link rel="pingback" href="https://everfitstore.com/xmlrpc.php" />
I/flutter (32004): 
I/flutter (32004):                  <script>document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className + ' yes-js js_active js'</script>
I/flutter (32004):              <script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>
I/flutter (32004): <title>Hello world! &#8211; Everfit Outfits</title>
I/flutter (32004): <meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large' />
I/flutter (32004): <script>window._wca = window._wca || [];</script>
I/flutter (32004): <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /><link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//stats.wp.com' />
I/flutter (32004): <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com'
```

The following permissions are already added in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

It would be great help if you guys help me find the issue. Do let me know if you need something else to know about the code. I would be very happy to provide. Thanks!

Comment: You are receiving the HTML content, so I can guess incorrect API configuration and endpoint. Try to include some code and more information.